# I made a converter in c++ that covert miles to km, km to miles, celcius to fahrenheit, fahrenheit to celcius

Tags: c++, user-interface

I made a converter that converts km to miles, miles to km, celcius to fehrenheit and fahrenheit to celcius what do you think of it and whats some improvments i could make

Also can anyone tell me how to make an UI in visual studio im not getting the option for it under Projects >> add new item.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

float km;
float mile;
float celcius;
float fahrenheit;
int conv;
bool running = true;

while (running == true) {


    cout << "\nWelcome to the converter" << endl;
    cout << "To convert Miles to Kilometres press 1" << endl;
    cout << "To convert Kilometres to Miles press 2" << endl;
    cout << "To convert Celcius to Fahrenheit press 3 " << endl;
    cout << "To convert Fahrenheit to Celcius press 4 " << endl;
    cout << "Enter conversion: ";

    cin >> conv ;

    if (conv == 1)
    {

        cout << "\nEnter miles to convert: ";
        cin >> mile;
        cout << mile * 8 / 5;

    }

    else if (conv == 2)
    {

        cout << "\nEnter kilometres to convert: ";
        cin >> km;
        cout << km * 5 / 8;

    }

    else if (conv == 3)
    {

        cout << "\nEnter Celcius to convert to Fahrenheit: ";
        cin >> celcius;
        cout << (celcius * 9 / 5) + 32;

    }

    else if (conv == 4) 
    {

        cout << "\nEnter Fahrenheit to convert to celcius: ";
        cin >> fahrenheit;
        cout << (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;

    }

    else {
        cout << "\nError\n";
    }

}
}
```

Comment: For UI there are many options, MFC is old school Windows UI development but it's grossly outdated. My personal favorite for UI design is Qt, it also supports a JS-like markup language which can make testing and building new designs much more streamlined.

Comment: This is two questions in one. The first should probably be asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The second should be asked by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code reviewed and updated.

See below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float km { 0.0 };
    float mile { 0.0 };
    float celcius { 0.0 };
    float fahrenheit { 0.0 };
    unsigned int selection { 0U };
    bool running { true };

    while (running) {


        std::cout << R"(
Welcome to the converter

To convert Miles to Kilometres press 1
To convert Kilometres to Miles press 2
To convert Celcius to Fahrenheit press 3
To convert Fahrenheit to Celcius press 4

To end the program, press 0

Enter selection:
)";

        std::cin >> selection ;

        switch (selection)
        {
            case 0:
                running = false;
                std::cout << "\n\nEnd of Program\n\n";
                break;

            case 1:
                std::cout << "\nEnter miles to convert: ";
                std::cin >> mile;
                std::cout << "\n" << mile * 8.0 / 5.0  << " km\n";
                break;

            case 2:
                std::cout << "\nEnter kilometres to convert: ";
                std::cin >> km;
                std::cout << "\n" << km * 5.0 / 8.0 << " miles\n";
                break;

            case 3:
                std::cout << "\nEnter Celcius to convert to Fahrenheit: ";
                std::cin >> celcius;
                std::cout << "\n" << celcius * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0 << " Fahrenheit\n" ;
                break;

            case 4:
                std::cout << "\nEnter Fahrenheit to convert to celcius: ";
                std::cin >> fahrenheit;
                std::cout << "\n" << (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9 << " Celcius\n";
                break;

            default:
                std::cerr << "\n\n**** Error. Wrong selection ****\n";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

UI --> QT